# Applescript: "can't get tab group 1 of window" (El Capitan)

Tags: applescript, audio, macos

The following is an applescript that I use to change audio output devices:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            click radio button "Output"
            if (selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1) then
                set selected of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
                set deviceselected to "Headphones"
            else
                set selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
                set deviceselected to "MX279"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

It worked on Yosemite, but when I updated to El Capitan it is giving me the following error:

```
"System Events got an error: Can't get tab group 1 of window \"Sound\" of application process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index"
```

I'm pretty unfamiliar with applescript, so any ideas why this might be happening will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first part of your script you load the `Sound` preference pane. It can happen that the pane isn't fully loaded before you send commands to it in the second part of the script. The error says that the `tab group 1` (the one that contains the `Output` tab) doesn't exist at the moment you are trying to access it.

To make sure the `tab group 1` exists, we can wait for it with these two lines:

```
repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
end repeat
```

The full script:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
        end repeat
        tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            click radio button "Output"
            if (selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1) then
                set selected of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
                set deviceselected to "Headphones"
            else
                set selected of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
                set deviceselected to "MX278"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Do you know why this was working for about 9 months prior and only now started acting up? System lag from El Capitan, maybe?

Comment: Good question. To be honest, I don't know.

Comment: Might you have any input for this question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217148/using-apple-script-to-manage-sound-output-selection

Comment: If you use "window 1" instead of "window 'sound' to refer to the window, it will also word on systems which run a non english system.