# How to programmatically change audio output to built in speakers ALWAYS

Tags: terminal, command-line, audio, unix, speakers

I've seen answers like [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439757/how-to-remotely-automatically-switch-a-macs-audio-output-device) but what I'm trying to do is programmatically ALWAYS set the audio output to built-in speakers regardless of which row item the Mac is currently tuned to.

In the code below (cited from the above link), the user selects between items 3 and 4. We know that built in speakers are always item 1, so is there a simpler way to achieve this where you send a shell command to always set the audio output to Built-in speakers?

```
(*
 Applescript to toggle between two sound outputs by Line number, ¬
 as they appear in the Sound Control Panel. Based on code by ¬
 Arthur Hammer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209434/85275
 *)

 set internal to 1 --internal speakers
 set appletv to 3 --Follows internal speakers and separator line for Airplay devices

 tell application "System Preferences"
   activate
   set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
 end tell


 tell application "System Events"
   tell application process "System Preferences"
  repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
  end repeat
  tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
      click radio button "Output"
      if (selected of row internal of table 1 of scroll area 1) then
          set selected of row appletv of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
      else
          set selected of row internal of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
      end if
  end tell
   end tell
 end tell
 tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: I've actually been working with  switchaudio-osx but I'm trying to figure out a solution that's independent of that :/

Comment: There is no built in way to switch audio via command line

Comment: I see. Do you know how the code that I referenced in the question achieved that? they're clearly not using switchaudio-osx

Comment: That code just programmatically controls the GUI.  As long as your device is on the row that the script references, it will work.  If yours is different, you’ll get different results. (I’m not a fan as I prefer Bash scripting)

Comment: Yes exactly! I just want to know how can I use that code to ALWAYS select built in speaker regardless of which row the output is currently. Does that make sense? Like regardless of if the current selection is at #3 item or #2, I want it to come back to built in speakers every single time. I hope I was able to explain myself?

Comment: You make complete sense and I agree with you.  I’m sure there is a way in AppleScript, but I’m not the guy to do it.  I learned to program in C, then C++ and finally Java.  AppleScript is a frustrating language for me so I avoided it.

Comment: Gotchu. Well anywyas, thanks for the input regardless.

Comment: @Allan Ah interesting. I didn't realize that AppleScript actually shows you what's going on (manipulating GUI as you said). I didn't know that it couldn't run in the background. Do you know bash always runs in the background?

Comment: Bash scripts run in a sub-shell (non-interactive).  They can in either the foreground or background.