# How to use Applescript to set output sound volume

Tags: applescript, audio, system-settings, sound-volume

I want to tweak the Applescript I use to select the sound output, to also dial the output volume up to 100%.

```
(*
Applescript to toggle between two sound outputs by Line number, ¬
as they appear in the Sound Control Panel. Based on code by ¬
Arthur Hammer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209434/85275
*)

set internal to 1 --internal speakers
set batcave to 3 --Bat Cave

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat until exists tab group 1 of window "Sound"
        end repeat
        
        -- I added this line to dial the volume up to 100%
        set volume output volume 1.0
        
        tell tab group 1 of window "Sound"
            click radio button "Output"
            if (selected of row internal of table 1 of scroll area 1) then
                set selected of row batcave of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
            else
                set selected of row internal of table 1 of scroll area 1 to true
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
--tell application "System Preferences" to quit
--remove the comment '--' tag above to make the control panel quit afterwards, leave for testing.
```

The error is:

```
tell current application
    set volume «class pcap» "System Preferences" output volume 1.0
Result:
error "System Events got an error: Can’t make application process \"System Preferences\" into type small real." number -1700 from application process "System Preferences" to small real
```

I guess I'm missing some contextualizing commands like "tell..." in front of the "set column" command. Suggestions?

I'm running MacOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

Comment: Did they change the `set volume` command? I thought it had to be an integer, e.g. 100. That said, it's an applescript command and doesn't belong to either system events or system preferences.

Comment: @Mockman I saw that somewhere but couldn't find it. Everything else says 0-100, which seems to work right.

Comment: There are two references to it that I am aware of. You can find it in the Language Guide under [Commands Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW44). You can also find it in the dictionary for the Standard Additions (File > Open Dictionary…). The command is the same either way and seems to work identically but I think the former is more correct. Actually, it looks like you can use a real but it's treated as a percentage, e.g. '1.0' = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set volume output volume` command is a **Standard Additions** command, but you are using it inside of a **System Events** `tell block`.  If you want to keep that line of code just where it is in your example, change it to this...

```
my (set volume output volume 100) -- if 1.0 fails, try 100
```

---

**Or try this...**

```
set internal to 1 --internal speakers
set batcave to 3 --Bat Cave

set volume output volume 100

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
```

Comment: Copied your code in place of mine, tried with both 100 and 1.0, same result: tell application "System Events"
 exists tab group 1 of window "Sound" of application process "System Preferences"
 get application process "System Preferences"
Result:
error "Can’t make «class pcap» \"System Preferences\" of application \"System Events\" into the expected type." number -1700 from «class pcap» "System Preferences"

Is there a different/better place for the command?

Comment: Yes remove that entire line of code from where it is... And place it right after your `set batcave` command.  Check my updated post.

Comment: That fixed the error. But what's happening is that, first, the volume gets changed, and second, the output is switched to BatCave (an Apple TV), at which point the volume gets cranked back down to 40% or so. It's always done this and I don't know why, but that's when I want to crank the volume. Any ideas? Perhaps this is a separate question...

Comment: Basically the thing you need to realize is that the `set volume output volume 100` command needs to be separate from within any other `tell blocks`.  So another option would be to exit out of any `tell blocks` with `end tell` then insert your `set volume output volume 100` then after that `tell application "System Events"` ...  OR you can simply place the `set volume output volume 100` at the very end of your script.

Comment: Got it. As it turns out, it takes about 10 seconds between the time the output  device is switched, to the time the sound begins coming out of the stereo via the AppleTV, and it's not until then that the volume gets adjusted down. So I'll have to put a delay in before the set volume output command, until I can figure out why the AppleTV is telling the Mac "turn me down."